# Calling Button-Clicked Function From Code

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a function set up in my code like so:

> -(IBAction) buttonClicked: (id) sender{
>
> //various expressions here
>
> }

The question is, how can I call this buttonClicked() function from somewhere else in the code, without requiring a user click the button.  For example, how can I call it from viewDidLoad()?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling in the same file, you can use:

```
[self buttonClicked:self];
```

Depending on what your method does.